How to perform `npm search` in custom registry that requires a token?
If I understand correctly, I can specify registry url ad hoc in the command directly:
npm search <packageName> --json --registry <registry>

The problem now is that my endpoint requires authentication and while npm install <private_package> works, npm search <keywords> --registry <registry> will fail with 401 or 403.
$ npm search alfons --registry <registry>
npm error code E401
npm error Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

$ npm search alfons --registry <registry>:NpmToken.123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000
npm error code E403
npm error 403 403 Forbidden - GET <registry>:NpmToken.***/-/v1/search?text=alfons&size=20&from=0&quality=0.65&popularity=0.98&maintenance=0.5
npm error 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm error 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm error 403 on a server you do not have access to.

How do I make it work, or what workaround can I use?

maybe related:
npm search private registry
Query npmjs registry via api
